# Why does the modulus operator not extend to other data types besides integer types?

Tags: c, numbers, modulus, primitive-types

Why does the modulus operator only extends to primitive types such ints, longs shorts etc and not floating data types like floats and doubles?

Comment: You can use [`fmod()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod) for modulo on floats and doubles

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define modulus.

`13 % 5` is `3` because that's what's left over when you do the division in the integer domain.

In the real domain (where you're not restricted to integer results), the result of `13.0 % 5.0` will be zero because thirteen divides evenly by five, giving `1.6`.

Now C does *have* a floating point modulus function `fmod` but it's more a hybrid between the two domains. For example, `fmod (18.5, 4.2)` gives `1.7`, the amount left over when the maximum *integral* number of `4.2` values are subtracted from `18.5` without going negative.

But that's not with the `%` modulus operator.

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with how decimals in most division problems never end(You can keep adding more zeros to the dividend, and you'll just get more zeros in the quotient). especially when you're dealing with repeating decimals. That is what I think when it comes to why the modulus operator only does integer division(mainly because you get to point where you can't continue).